Jfrog - Anonymous User - Set the Login page as the start page
I just upgraded the Jfrog Artifactory to the last version (7.77.8) and I saw the anonymous user have access everywhere in UI. I followed all the instructions and "Set the Login page as the start page" not working.
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/administrator-users
Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
